# About the common exercise using Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

A common exercise using Weierstrass Theorem is:

> If a continuous function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies:
>
> $$\int _{[0,1]}x^kf(x)dx=0$$
>
> for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f\equiv 0$

This implies that a continuous function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be "embedded" in the space of sequences of real numbers (namely, for each $f$, define the sequence $c_k:=\int _{[0,1]}x^kf(x)dx$). This holds since if $c_k=d_k$ for every $k$, then $f-g\equiv 0$.

This strikes to me as an analogue for the Riesz-Fischer Theorem. Is there some theory about this, or is it really just a common exercise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking at it the wrong way. Really what is going on is that the space of polynomials is dense in the space of continuous functions wrt the supremum norm, while the space of continuous functions is dense in $L^2 ([0,1])$ wrt the $L^2$ norm. Since uniform convergence implies convergence in $L^2$ on a finite measure space, it follows that polynomials are dense in $L^2([0,1]) $. Now in a Hilbert space, if something is orthogonal to a dense set then it is zero, so any such $f $ must be zero a.e. Finally a continuous function which is zero a.e. must be identically zero.